# Get the timestamp when a async task has finished

Tags: java, asynchronous, future

If I have the following ExecutorService to perform a task, how can I get it to print the time of task being completed? Should I add getCurrentTime() after future.get()?

```
Future future = executorService.submit(new Callable(){
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Asynchronous Callable");
        return "I finished";
    }
});

System.out.println("Status:" + future.get());
```

Comment: It's possible, but with a bunch of work using the [`ManagedTaskListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedTaskListener.html)

Comment: What happens if you print it inside the `Callable`?